# Flow требует необязательных параметров при приведении типов

Tags: javascript, flow

Имеется следующий код с использованием flow

```
function foo(x: type2): any {}

type type1 = {
  a: boolean
}

type type2 = {
  a: boolean,
  b?: string
}

let obj: type1 = {
  a: true
}

foo(obj);
```

В данном случае, flow падает с ошибкой

> Cannot call 'foo' with 'obj' bound to 'x' because property 'b' is missing in 'type1' [1] but exists in 'type2' [2]. [prop-missing]

Почему такое происходит, ведь в данном случае параметр b необязательный и не должен требоваться при проверке типов?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в type2 требуется, чтобы поля `e` либо не было совсем, либо оно имело тип `string`, а `type1` не содержит это поле, а значит не накладывает на него никаких ограничений, поэтому следующий код допустим:

```
let obj: type1 = {
  a: true,
  e: 9999,
}
```

Очевидно, что такой объект не совместим с `type2`, а значит и `type1` в общем случае не совместим с `type2`.

Я ожидал, что это можно исправить, сделав `type1` точным

```
type type1 = {|
  a: boolean,
|}
```

но так почему-то тоже не работает. Зато работает такое изменение:

```
type type1 = {
  a: boolean,
  e?: void,
}
```

Кстати, если речь идёт о литеральном объекте, то можно просто убрать указание типа:

```
let obj = {
  a: true,
}
```

и всё заработает.

Comment: К сожалению, это не литеральный объект, поэтому так не сработает